# Как сделать анимацию вращающегося linear-gradient background?

Tags: html, css, css-animation

У меня есть фон с линейным градиентом, и я хочу сделать анимацию на его вращение. Мой код не работает. Чего мне не хватает?
Мне нужно вращать сам градиент, а не элемент. Я хочу сделать анимацию, как карточки по этой ссылке: https://nuxt.com/. Это возможно только если анимировать сам background (Там есть padding, и он должен быть с градиентом, так что на самом деле анимируется фон элемента позади него, а не border).

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.block__bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(360deg,#00dc82,#fff,rgba(54,228,218,.7),rgba(29,224,177,.3));
  animation: gradient-rotate 5s linear 0s infinite reverse;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

@keyframes gradient-rotate {
  0% {
    background: linear-gradient(360deg,#00dc82,#fff,rgba(54,228,218,.7),rgba(29,224,177,.3));
  }
  to {
    background: linear-gradient(0deg,#00dc82,#fff,rgba(54,228,218,.7),rgba(29,224,177,.3));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__bg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вращение по часовой стрелке относительно центра?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно вращать псевдоэлемент вместо самого блока:

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  width: 150%;
  height: 150%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0turn);
  background: linear-gradient(#00dc82, #fff, #36e4dab3, #1de0b14d);
  animation: gradient-rotate 5s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes gradient-rotate {
  to { transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(1turn); }
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Для всех браузеров, кроме Firefox и Safari:

```css
@property --my-angle {
  syntax: '<angle>';
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0turn;
}

.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(var(--my-angle), #00dc82, #fff, #36e4dab3, #1de0b14d);
  animation: gradient-rotate 5s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes gradient-rotate {
  to { --my-angle: 1turn; }
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: кто то минусанул - я сколько смог исправил

Comment: @MonkeyMutant: спасибо, но вроде не наблюдаю минуса :)

Comment: щас нету - я видел -

Comment: @MonkeyMutant: ну, мне тоже показалось, что мигнуло что-то... Думал, что у меня глюк.

Comment: я сегодня частенько наблюдал фантомные минусы в разных вопросах, возможно сервак лагает)

Comment: Как у вы хорошо написали решение! Если кого-то интересует единица `turn`, тогда добро пожаловать [на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/angle#%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81)

Comment: @NL993: спасибо. Ох, быстрее бы поддержка `@property` появилась везде. `:has()` вроде работает потихоньку :)

Answer (score 3):

Думаю как-то так, шагов можно больше прописать, анимацию как я понял Вы хотели туда-сюда крутить, поэтому поставил `alternate-reverse` остальное сами добавите по вкусу:

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.block__bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(360deg,#00dc82,#fff,rgba(54,228,218,.7),rgba(29,224,177,.3));
  animation: gradient-rotate 2s linear 0s infinite alternate-reverse;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

@keyframes gradient-rotate {
  10% {
    background: linear-gradient(324deg,#00dc82,#fff,rgba(54,228,218,.7),rgba(29,224,177,.3));
  }
  20% {
    background: linear-gradient(288deg,#00dc82,#fff,rgba(54,228,218,.7),rgba(29,224,177,.3));
  }
  30% {
    background: linear-gradient(252deg,#00dc82,#fff,rgba(54,228,218,.7),rgba(29,224,177,.3));
  }
  40% {
    background: linear-gradient(216deg,#00dc82,#fff,rgba(54,228,218,.7),rgba(29,224,177,.3));
  }
  50% {
    background: linear-gradient(180deg,#00dc82,#fff,rgba(54,228,218,.7),rgba(29,224,177,.3));
  }
  60% {
    background: linear-gradient(144deg,#00dc82,#fff,rgba(54,228,218,.7),rgba(29,224,177,.3));
  }
  70% {
    background: linear-gradient(108deg,#00dc82,#fff,rgba(54,228,218,.7),rgba(29,224,177,.3));
  }
  80% {
    background: linear-gradient(72deg,#00dc82,#fff,rgba(54,228,218,.7),rgba(29,224,177,.3));
  }
  90% {
    background: linear-gradient(36deg,#00dc82,#fff,rgba(54,228,218,.7),rgba(29,224,177,.3));
  }
  100% {
    background: linear-gradient(0deg,#00dc82,#fff,rgba(54,228,218,.7),rgba(29,224,177,.3));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__bg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Интересно просто, как у них (по ссылке) получилось. Там линейная анимация без пошаговых процентов. Что-то я упустил.

Comment: Там вращается `after` если Вам нужен фон то скорее тот вариант не подойдет, но можете попробовать, я тоже сначала думал про трансформ, но потом сосредоточился на фоне) В Вашем случае угол градиента это не то же самое что градус вращения (тот высчитывается гораздо проще, хотя эффект выглядит одинаково), просто представьте что вам проще воткнуть циркуль и вращать бумагу или взять линейку и чертить линии под разными углами — примерно такая разница между ними.

Comment: @OleksiiBinetskyi ну вот с `before` вариант может подойти.